# Specify natural languages you know in Careers 2.0

Tags: support, status-bydesign, jobs, languages

Until I was called for a job meeting I haven't even noticed, that CV at Careers 2.0 is missing one vital point. Knowledge of different natural languages. It would be nice to have section where you can add languages one by one and specify their knowledge for spoken and written types.

Is this feature planed for future development or maybe it is present and I just haven't found it?

Comment: I was totally going to prove you wrong ... but it's indeed not there. Could have sworn it was.

Comment: Same here. Came to interview and was asked this question and pointed, that there was no such info in CV. I was a bit shoked.

Comment: I don't think it's appropriate to say it's by-design. I suggest it to be retagged to [feature-request], even if it's not planned to be done in nearest future.

Answer (score 1):

At this time, there's no individual section for (natural) language skills on you Careers 2.0 CV. They can be included in the *Background* section at the end. Or, if you consider them crucial, they can also be included in the *Personal statement* section at the top.

By the way, here's a great question with a great answer on our Workplace site:

[How Should I Indicate Language Proficiency on my Resume?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/10006/how-should-i-indicate-language-proficiency-on-my-resume)

Comment: How much time would it take to add such feature to Careers?

Comment: I've never been to Careers II, but if programming languages are structured and enumerated rather than just being some text box, why not spoken languages?